# How to use Firebase Auth to Authenticate a Password secured REST API?

Tags: java, firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, flutter-dependencies

I am developing an app which use 2 things, `Firebase Auth` and a Custom `REST API` Made with Java Jersey.

I prefer Firebase Auth because then I don't have to save the Password, Hash etc in my database and the password reset process is easy.

But my REST API is using basic authentication, which means it uses a username and a password to generate a  `JWT Token.` Now because of this, I have no option but to save password, Hash etc in the database.

Instead, I prefer if I can check username/password with Firebase Auth and inform the server it's okay to generate the JWT Token.

What's the recommended solution for this?

Comment: dont use basic auth in the server for this. Generate a token on the device using the Firebase Client SDK or REST API, send the token to the API and validate it. I have that implement in Java Android, and python Flask. If some code may be helpful, let me know.

Comment: @PedroRodrigues For client apps, I am using Flutter for mobile and Java for web. So generate token in client side using Firebase SDK? Then pass it into server and validate with Firebase Admin SDK? Is that what you meant?

Comment: That is correct. That is what they push you for, and that is what I am doing, and its not that complicated actually. its just a ton of config params to get the Admin SDK going, but you do it once anyway.

Comment: @PedroRodrigues ok. Any code examples?